# sklearn.tree.export_graphviz values do not add up to samples

Tags: data-mining, python, cart, scikit-learn

When I run tree.export_graphviz() after training a sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier() on my data, I get some leaf nodes where the samples count doesn't match the value array, like this:

```
4 [label="entropy = 0.0000\nsamples = 420\nvalue = [ 676.    0.]", shape="box"] ;
```

I was thinking that the counts in the value array should add up to the sample count for the counts that match each category in the dependent variable. Looks like that is not the case...so what do the numbers in the value array mean??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a random forest the cases are bagged (bootstrap resamples for each tree) but instead of actually including multiple copies of some cases scikit just adjust the weights of those cases which results in about a 30% speed up. It appears the code to count the values uses these weights while the code to count the number of samples does not.

You can try growing the rf with bootstrap=False to verify.